# combine several regexes with negative and positive lookahead

Tags: regex, ansible

I would like to negate this regex that matches if the ip is 1.2.3.4 **and** followed by 'myhost' but i want it to match if the ip is **not** 1.2.3.4 but it is followed by myhost

```
^(1\.2\.3\.4) (?=myhost)
```

I tried doing this but it does not work.

```
^(?!(1\.2\.3\.4)) (?=hostname)
```

I also would like to negate this regex that matches the hostname but I would like to match if the hostname is not "myhost"

```
(?<=1\.2\.3\.4) (myhost)
```

the regex matches myhost if its preceeded by 1.2.3.4

the idea is to check some /etc/hosts files and make sure the ip matches the hostname and viceverza.. I will be doing this in ansible.. so if the regex can be combined in one line..
in a nutshell i want to test that   are always correct. I am using ansible fact to find the ip and hostname.. i have just problem with the regexes.

edit: as requested some examples:

i have the following 4 lines:

```
1.2.3.4 hostname (1)
1.2.3.5 hostname (2)
1.2.3.4 otherhost (3)
1.2.3.5 otherhost (4)
```

line (1) nothing should match. 
in lines (2) it should match the ip address but without the espace after it. 
in line (3) `otherhost` should match. 
In line (4) both should match..

If any of the regex match it will be replaced with ansible with line (1) this is to make sure the /etc/host is correct. does not have typos or inconsistencies.

thank you.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/eLsR6J/1) working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Lookarounds are zero-length assertion, you have to add regex that matches IP:

```
^(?!1\.2\.3\.4)\d+(?:\.\d+){3} (?=hostname)
```

This will match IP address followed by `hostname` that is not equal to `1.2.3.4`

Comment: and how to do the opoosite match the `hostname` that is preceded by ip `1.2.3.4` that is not hostname. and is it possible to combine the two in one?

Comment: @danidar: Sorry, I don't get you. Please, [editi your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1402416/edit) and add some examples that you want to match and some that must not.